# Displaying Media Query list horizontally

Tags: css, squarespace

I am working in Squarespace trying to get this media query code to display the showcased images horizontally not vertical. And at the same time make them smaller. I have tried using "inline-block" and "display: flex;" but nothing seems to work. I only need to get this to work on a phone screen, so it's only the media query that's changable I think.

Is there a solution to this, since it's through Squarespace?

The code looks like this:

```
.section-border{opacity:0!important;}
.page-section, .section-background{background:transparent!important;}
.site-wrapper{background: linear-gradient(220deg, #CEC3FF, #cec3ff 10%, #ffffff 50%)!important;}


.list-item-content {  margin-top:-58%;  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0) 25%, 75%);   padding: 1rem;  transition: all 0.5s;  z-index:99;  opacity:0}

.list-item:hover .list-item-content { transition: all 1s; opacity:1}.list-item-content *{color:#FFF!important}

.list-item-media {transition: all 1s;filter:grayscale(1);}.list-item:hover  .list-item-media {transition: all 1s;filter:grayscale(0)!important;}

@media only screen and(max-width:640px){ .list-item-content { 
opacity:1!important;
margin-top:-60%; } 
.list-item-media{ filter:grayscale(0)!important; }}
```

I have tried these solutions:

```
@media only screen and(max-width:640px){ .list-item-content { 
opacity:1!important;
margin-top:-60%; } 
.list-item-media{ 
filter:grayscale(0)!important;
display: inline-block; }}
```

```
@media only screen and(max-width:640px){ .list-item-content { 
opacity:1!important;
margin-top:-60%; } 
.list-item-media{ 
filter:grayscale(0)!important;
display: flex; }}
```

Comment: CSS on its own, without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please present a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML code because it's squarespace.

Comment: Get it either via "view source code" in your browser, or if that doesn't work (because parts of it are assembled via JavaScript), get it from the DOM inspector view.